# Show duplicate values while merging lists using Union in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to merge lists using Union in LINQ but I don't want to remove duplicate values.

```
WordJEntities db = new WordJEntities();
string[] barrayk = new string[6] {"12","13","14","12","13","15"};

var sppk = from row in db.table1 where row.Id == 12 select new{row.name };
IEnumerable<object> data8k = null;
for (int i = 0; i < barrayk.Length; i++)
{
    string ajk = barrayk[i]; 
    int ajjk = Convert.ToInt32(ajk);
    var data7k = from row in db.table1 where row.Id == ajjk select new { row.name };
    if (i == 0)
    { 
        data8k = sppk.ToList().Union(data7k).ToList(); 
    }
    else
    { 
        data8k = data8k.Union(data7k).ToList(); 
    }
    int jrj = data8k.ToList().Count;
}

string s4 = js.Serialize(data8k);
```

The output must have 6 records but it has only 4 records.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve with all these (weird) LINQ `Union` (`Concat`) and `ToList` calls is equivalent of simply creating a single list and using `Add` / `AddRange` methods.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.Concat` instead of `.Union`.

Answer (score 0):

If they are of the same type then `AddRange` should work too.

1. `AddRange` preserves the order of the lists, but it doesn't remove any duplicates which Union does, but does sully the original list.

   ```
   sppk.ToList().AddRange((data7k).ToList());
   ```
2. If you do not want to modify the original list then use `Concat` as suggested

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DowMm6) that demonstrate that.